# Shared coordinates between elements in SVG

Tags: svg

I would like to share coordinates between two or more elements.

**My example in peudo-Code :**

```
<point xml:id="myPoint" x="10" y="20" />

<circle point="url(#myPoint)" r="10" />
<circle point="url(#myPoint)" r="50" />
```

I've seen [IRI references](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/linking.html) that have the best match with that I searched, but :

- First, there is no nodes of type "point" existing.
- Second, IRI references doesn't support any attributes.

With SVG format and specifications (no javascript code), Is there a way to have many elements which **reference** the same coordinates ?

Thus, I just have to manipulate the point "myPoint" to change the coordinate of all elements that reference it.

I hope my english isn't so bad and thanks for your answers.

Comment: You could use a `<g>` element together with `transform="translate()"` to have a similar effect. Not exactly the same, but may be close enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a group `<g>` element to transform the origin. If you omit co-ordinates then objects will be drawn there.

```
<g transform="translate(10, 20)">
  <circle r="10" />
  <circle r="50" />
</g>
```

Comment: Nice to meet you and thanks for your answer, it work great with a circle, a rectangle and some positioned elements. I know this is not mentioned in my question, is it possible to do anything in the same kind for polygons, polylines on certains points. Is this the only way ?

Comment: This works for polygons and polylines too. If you still have problems, ask another question with the specifics of the issue you have.